# How can I set up my swagger-node route to accept any content type?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-node

Currently, I have my Swagger YAML set up to accept `application/json` by default for each route with the following on the top-level Swagger definition:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: my App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:5054
# basePath prefixes all resource paths
basePath: /
schemes:
# tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
```

I now have a route that can return files, and I don't want to have to specify all the potential files that may be returned. I have seen on the Swagger GitHub page that there may be some sort of wildcard that allows any content type to be returned. I have tried the following in my route:

```yaml
get:
   description: Download a single document
   operationId: getDocument
   produces: []
```

but Swagger UI will not allow me to send the request in the UI, as it sees this as having no `Accept` field populated.

Then:

```yaml
get:
   description: Download a single document
   operationId: getDocument
   produces: */*
```

But Swagger UI throws an error stating `unidentified alias "/*"`. I also tried `\*/*` just in case it was something to do with needing to be escaped but that didn't work.

Finally:

```yaml
get:
   description: Download a single document
   operationId: getDocument
   produces: "*/*"
```

This one allowed me to test the route in Swagger UI but the response still failed validation and claimed the expected content type was still to be `application/json`.

Is there a wildcard that works or am I trying to do something Swagger isn't set up for?

Answer (score 0):

`*/*` matches all media types and is equivalent to `application/octet-stream`.

`produces` is an array, so you need to use the array syntax. Also, since it's YAML, `'*/*'` needs to be enclosed in quotes, because `*` is a special character used to indicate [alias nodes](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#*%20alias//).

```yaml
produces:
  - '*/*'
  # or
  - application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Hi Helen - tried that, and got the following error: `Error: Response validation failed: invalid content type (image/png).  These are valid: application/json, */*, application/octet-stream`

Comment: Yeah. The response validation.

Comment: Which server/framework do you use? How does the validation code look like?

Comment: Validation is through swagger, no custom validation code exists. The backend is swagger.

Comment: "Swagger" is a collective name for [lots of projects](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/). Which one does your server actually use? swagger-tools, swagger-node-express, springfox, ...?

Comment: Oops, sorrry! Swagger-node is what we're using